# Is the [evolution] tag too generic?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, ambiguous-tags

I came across the [evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution) tag because of this suggested edit (now approved)

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3270491

The proposed wiki is

> Play Framework evolutions are plain SQL scripts used to track and organized database schema changes allowing developers to stay synchronized with each other.

However when I looked at the questions I found that, while some of them are actually about the Play Framework, many others are about several unrelated topics, such as evolution of APIs over time, a linux mail client, transition from a framework to another or more generically anything that may evolve over time.

[evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution) looks too generic to be used a synonymous for [playframework-evolutions](/questions/tagged/playframework-evolutions) and I think it's a good candidate for burnination.

I went ahead and replaced [evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution) with [playframework-evolutions](/questions/tagged/playframework-evolutions) whenever applicable, what is appropriate to do now?

Burninate [evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution), add a generic description or something else?

### Update

After the discussion in the comments, it looks like the only valid use of the tag is currently as synonym for [playframework-evolutions](/questions/tagged/playframework-evolutions), since in any other case it was just used as meta information. I removed [evolution](/questions/tagged/evolution) from all the remaining questions and I'm turning this into a [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request).

Comment: I would clean up all entries in [tag:evolution] as it is currently just metainformation about a question, then make it a duplicate of [tag:playframework-evolutions]. It is more likely to be found that way, because typing 'evolution' will suggest 'playframework-evolutions' I believe.

Comment: I agree on cleaning up the entries, not sure about synonymization though. `evolution` looks generic enough for leading to frequent misuse.

Comment: If the user types `evolution` in the tag box, the suggestion will only be `playframework-evolutions`. If they tag a question with it, it will be auto-corrected to `playframework-evolutions`, which will be corrected pretty soon. Simpy deleting it will not work, as it will be created again shortly afterwards. Leaving it doesn't sound useful to me. Furthermore, I don't see any on-topic uses of "evolution", other than the case where it is about the framework.

Comment: @Samurai8, makes sense. Too bad I cannot propose the synonym myself.

Comment: @Samurai8 ok, I cleaned up all the entries, and turned this into a [synonym-request]

Comment: 0 questions -> the tag will be deleted -> there's little need for it to be a synonym (I think we'd just be asked for it to be misused if we make it one). And I hope you were careful in your removal of the tag, i.e. replaced by a more descriptive tag where applicable, rather than just removed it.

Comment: @Dukeling I see, still there are zero questions using the tag since I cleaned them up. There quite a few legitimate use of [evolution] for Play Framework Evolutions questions.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella If you type in "evolution" in the tags of a question, [tag:playframework-evolutions] will show up, so it doesn't need to be a synonym (IMO). And it existing, synonym or not, makes it a candidate for misuse, as you saw from the mistagged questions.